# EaselJS 0.61 Ticker issue

Tags: javascript, methods, easeljs, ticker

**Situation**

I'm using easeljs within a jquery plugin and have set it up without issue. Here is a snippet of the code I use:

```
/**
*
* FUNCTION - SETUP_CANVAS
*
**/
setupcanvas: function() {
    /* Prepare the canvas for Easel interaction */
    params.objHTMLEaselObject = new createjs.Stage("LoL-canvas");

    /* Enable mouse/touch events */
    params.objHTMLEaselObject.mouseEventsEnabled = true;

    params.text = new createjs.Text("Test", "20px Arial", "#ff7700");
    params.text.x = 100;
    params.text.textBaseLine = "alphabetic";

    params.objHTMLEaselObject.addChild(params.text);

    /* Set ticker for the stage */
    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(params.intDesiredFPS);
    createjs.Ticker.addListener("tick", methods.tick());
    console.log('canvas is set up');

},
/**
*
* FUNCTION - TICK
*
**/
tick : function(event) {
    params.intTicks++;
    params.text.set({text: params.intTicks});
    console.log('tick: '+params.intTicks);
    params.objHTMLEaselObject.update();
}

### Properties set elsewhere ###
params.intDesiredFPS = 30;
params.intTicks = 0;
```

As you can see, I am setting most properties to the javascript object; all this functionality works fine and without issue. The ticker is by default set to zero. This does get changed and the canvas reflects the change by rendering "1"

**Problem**

The only way I can get the ticker to call is as shown, normally I would make the call without the brackets but for some reason, easel doesn't like that. Going beyond just that:

1) The event is undefined when I perform a console.log

2) The ticker only actually ticks once.

Please can you help me to understand what I am doing wrong here, I'm quite stumped and the documentation and internet has turned up very little information when used in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
createjs.Ticker.addListener("tick", new function(e) { methods.tick(e); });
```

Comment: Thanks for getting me halfway there, I'm so used to not having to use the "new" part

Comment: The error in the initial demo was the methods.tick was getting fired, and returning the value, instead of just passing the function.